# How to use only one echo for two array values in the same line

Tags: php, arrays

Just curiosity. Can I make this code with one echo only?

```
<div class="full_name">
    <?php echo $row['username']; echo $row['surname']?>
</div>
```

I tried things like:

```
<div class="full_name">
    <?php echo $row['username'], $row['surname']?>
</div>

<div class="full_name">
    <?php echo $row['username']['surname']?>
</div>

<div class="full_name">
    <?php echo $row['username','surname']?>
</div>
```

Nothing worked.

Comment: Why are people are so fast to downvote?

Comment: This can easily be found in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Although that first thing you tried should work, see https://3v4l.org/FsJG4

Comment: @Qirel Actually not only the first thing. Also second, because echo can output many parameters for example: echo $foo,$bar; will work. So for me "Nothing worked." doesn't make sense. Or author didn't wrote all details of problem.

Comment: @arbogastes When I wrote "*first thing you tried*", I ment `echo $row['username'], $row['surname']`, like my example shows (see the link). The others are invalid, because the second attempt is two-dimensional array (which of `$row` is likely one-dimensional), and the third doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Qirel Oh, yes. I see now. It was my oversight. Sorry. You are right :)

Comment: I understand how it could be confusing though, @arbogastes ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the two strings using the dot operator. `.`

Like this:

```
<?php echo $row['username']. ' ' . $row['surname']?>
```

You can also use `sprintf`. Like this:

```
<?php echo sprintf('%s %s', $row['username'], $row['surname']);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php echo $row['username']." ".$row['surname']?>
```

Comment: The quotes between are not needed though - they do absolutely nothing here. And "try this" answers are generally frowned upon - you should also include an explanation.

Comment: Why are you including a blank space in between the two variables? `."".` does absolutely nothing but make you type more.